# Perl: A script that searches for packages inside a directory

Tags: perl

A bit of context: I have csv files with data that I am moving to a database using Text::CSV_XS. I have about 12 tables. Im working with a Model/Data.pm DBI wrapper module which is the parent of "Model/Data/Table1.pm" modules, each of them representing a table. If I want to write something into Table 1 i need to write a script.pl wich does something like this:

```
my $table1_ds = App::Model::Data::Table1->new();
$table1_ds->insert(\@insert_data);
$table1_ds->commit;
```

I do not want to write this for each table. Furthermore, maybe new tables appear one day.

I want Perl to search for packages in "Model/Data/" and "get" or stores each package in a data structure such that I can use code like this:

```
for each $table_name(@table_names){
  my $table_name_ds = App::Model::Data::$table_name->new();
  $table_name_ds->insert(\@insert_data);
  $table_name_ds->commit;
}
```

How to I make a perl script that searches for packages inside a directory and stores the name inside a data structure (in the example, @table_names)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using `strict` (you should use `warnings` too).

```
for each $table_name (@table_names){
    no strict 'refs';
    require "App/Model/Data/$table_name.pm";
    my $table_name_ds = "App::Model::Data::$table_name"->new();
    $table_name_ds->insert(\@insert_data);
    $table_name_ds->commit;
}
```

But note that the first part does loading of the module in question. You really should do that somewhere else, before using the module. In other words, separate loading from the inserts.